# Homotopically equivalent manifolds and product with $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

I know that some manifolds which are homotopically equivalent become homeomorphic after taking the product with $\mathbb{R}$, e.g. $\mathbb{T}^{2}$ minus a point and $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ minus three points, or [Whitehead manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

I was wondering if there are some general conditions under which this happens, i.e. when given two homotopically equivalent $n-$manifolds $X_1$ and $X_2$ we have that $X_1\times\mathbb{R}$ and $X_2\times\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: You might appreciate [this paper by Mazur](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183524255) and [this](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~fw/an_outline_how_manifolds_relate_to_algebraic_geometry.pdf) more algebraic note by Waldhausen.